# In Thunderbird, while composing an email, how to convert it from plain text to HTML?

Tags: email, thunderbird

In Thunderbird, while composing an email, how to convert it from plain text to HTML? In general, I'd like to compose plain text emails by default. But sometimes, when I realized I need to insert HTML-supported elements in the email currently being composed, how do I convert it to HTML? If possible, after the current email is completed, I still want plain text email composition by default.

Comment: There’s _Options_ → _Delivery Format_, but it doesn’t change what the editor looks like for me.

Comment: I don't think that is possible. You have to decide before starting to compose the email. ("Holding down the Shift key before clicking on create a new message, or one of the reply options, switches from the default writing mode to the other.")

Comment: @DavidPostill: I tried holding down the Shift key and click 'Write' button, no option to switch to HTML format showed up.

Comment: @DanielB: In Windows Thunderbird 78.9.0 (64-bit), I could NOT find "Options → Delivery Format".

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I agree with the comment above that it's not possible. However, it's possible to workaround.

Upon composing a plain text email and realizing that it should be in HTML, you can do the following (which I tested in TB on Win10)...

1. Either hold down <kbd>Shift</kbd> and click the `Write` button on
   the main TB window ***OR*** click `Message` in the `New` menu on the Plain
   Text message window while holding down <kbd>Shift</kbd>. A new
   message window including a formatting toolbar should appear, where the
   presence of the formatting toolbar implies the format is HTML.
2. In the Plain Text window, type <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>A</kbd> to
   select the entire message.
3. Drag & drop the selection from the Plain Text window to the HTML
   window.
4. Close the Plain Text window.
5. Continue composing the message in the HTML window.

Of course in step 3, you can use any other copy & paste method if you prefer.

Answer (score 4):

The simplest method, in my view, is:

1. <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>s</kbd> or menu-item `File: Save` to save a draft copy of the current email under composition.
2. Right-click on that saved draft in the Drafts folder and shift-click on the `Edit as new message` option to bring up an HTML version of the email to continue editing.
3. Discard the original email pane.

Answer (score 1):

Not exactly what you've asked but some possible solution.

You can write your e-mails with **Markdown Here Revival** extension. It allows to toggle between text and markdown mode by one button. You can use text mode for insert html elements.

After you save your message you can also see the message as text or html toggling between by button of **Allow HTML Temp** extension: click on button - html, click plus Shift - raw text.

Answer (score 0):

Agree with the other answers, but want to add that according to [this Mozillazine KB article](https://kb.mozillazine.org/Plain_text_e-mail_(Thunderbird)):

> You don't need to re-configure Thunderbird if you want to send the occasional message in the other format. Just press the "Shift" key when clicking the "Write", "Reply", or "Reply to All" button and it will use the other format for that message. Unfortunately, this doesn't work for "Forward".

So at least you can decide at the point of starting a new email whether you want it to be plain text or HTML...